# How to hide a checkbox from django forms library and toggle its display attribute with Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms, dom-events

I have been making a form in html that has a checkbox and if checked it displays another checkbox using Javascript. I have now changed that form to use django's Form library but I don't know how to access the display attribute of the django input fields. I have tried the HideInput widget but all that doesn't hide the label just the box itself.

Any help on how to set the display attributes of django Form objects and/or how to toggle those attributes using Javascript would be great and/or how to code event attributes on django Forms would be great!

models.py:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
Contact = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=CheckboxInput())
More = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=CheckboxInput())
```

html page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 




$(function(){
$('#id_Contact').click(function(){
 if($('#id_Contact').is(':checked')){
    $('#id_More').show();
 }
  });
});

    function ifChecked(id, id2){
        var ele = document.getElementById(id);
        var ele2 = document.getElementById(id2);

        if(ele.checked){
            ele2.style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            ele2.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>

<form action="/contact/" method="post">
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```
from django.forms import CheckboxInput, HiddenInput

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
  Contact = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=CheckboxInput())
  More = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=HiddenInput())
```

You could use jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $('#id_Contact').click(function(){
     if($('#id_Contact').is(':checked')){$('#id_More').show();}
  });
});
```

Comment: That hides the checkbox but not the name "More" is there a way where I can make it a label and then hide that too?

Comment: Look for the label. it would have been generated as for="id_content", just hide that using jquery too.

Comment: How can I have it start hidden though? Also, the label itself doesn't have a separate ID, it just references the checkbox ID. How would I call on the label? @karthikr

Comment: Sorry, i should have realized that.. widget=forms.HiddenInput() instead of the style attribute

Comment: More = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
this also only hides the box itself :/

Comment: not sure if I understand your question, the html is shown above with the recent edits.
Another thing that I noticed though is that the jQuery code is called only when the page loads, not every time Contact is clicked, how can I change that? @karthikr

Comment: {% if not field.is_hidden %} {% endif %}

Comment: NameError: name 'CheckboxInput' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

u can try

{{ form.field_name_to_hide.as_hidden }}

in template